# Special characters in response using Google PHP API client

Tags: php, api, youtube, character

I'm using the Google PHP API Client to retrieve video information from Youtube. In the title of some video's there are special characters. Instead of "één", "eÌeÌn" is returned. I tried utf8_decode, but no luck with that.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mb_detect_encoding()` (http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to know what encoding is used for any text (and decode / encode it accordingly).

Comment: Tried that already. Got UTF-8 back, but utf8-decode didn't give me the right characters.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's something fun:

```
$ perl -e 'binmode(STDOUT, "utf8");' \
       -e 'print "e\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}\n";' \
  | iconv -c -f CP1252
eÌ
```

The output you're seeing can be explained by a string in UTF-8 (with graphemes decomposed) which has *at some point* been interpreted as though it were a string in Codepage 1252 (note that on the Web, if you don't specify which encoding something is it's assumed to be in CP1252). It would also have to be throwing out the invalid codepoints, which you are *not supposed to do*, but whatever.

Check everything that touches this string. Anything that isn't Unicode-aware needs to be replaced with something that is.